# System information on ssh-login suddenly disappeared?

Tags: ssh

When I connected to my RPi using ssh, I always had a line up there like

```
Linux airpi 3.18.7+ #755 PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:14:31 GMT 2015 armv6l
```

but suddenly it's gone now. Where can I check if it's enabled? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the date and time that kernel was compiled, not the current date and time. What you're seeing is the output of the `uname` command.

`/etc/init.d/motd` calls it and outputs it to `/var/run/motd.dynamic`

```
uname -snrvm > /var/run/motd.dynamic
```

Bash allows you to suppress display of the MOTD by creating a file in your home directory called .hushlogin.

If you don't have a .hushlogin, maybe /etc/init.d/motd was disabled, or the symlink to it in the appropriate /etc/rc#.d directory was removed.

Comment: Aahh, you're right! I don't have a .hushlogin file in my home directory and there are 5 symlinks in the /etc/rc*.d directories, so how can I check if /etc/init.d/motd is enabled or enable it at all?

Comment: Each of the symlinks in the /etc/rc#.d directories should point to something in the /etc/init.d directory.  The # equates to a run level, and 2 is the default runlevel.  init will go through and run the scripts in order, starting in /etc/rcS.d and then going to /etc/rc2.d.  The K scripts are kill, init calls them with the stop argument.  The S scripts are start.  So if there's no /etc/rc2.d/S01motd then /etc/init.d/motd won't be called.

Comment: See also this link for more about hushlogin.  https://debian-administration.org/article/546/Giving_yourself_a_quieter_SSH_login

Answer (score -1):

This article describes how to disable/enable/change the welcome message: https://serverfault.com/questions/407033/how-can-i-edit-the-welcome-message-when-ssh-start

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I can't find an answer to my question in your link. This is not a static message I'm talking about. It includes the date and time as well for instance.